# Magento login custumer and add product to cart in chrome

Tags: magento-2.1, login, magento-2.1.4, chrome-browser

After installation of magento 2.1.4, everything works very well on other browsers, except Chrome.

1. When a client registers, it is automatically connected but when it disconnects and tries to reconnect, nothing happens (redirection to the login page). I tried to lengthen the lifetime of cookies no change.
2. On the product display page when it clicks on Add to cart, an add notification is displayed but the product is not added to the cart.

I point out that everything walks nikel on other browsers.

Comment: Your current domain is using `localhost`? e.g: `http://localhost/mage2`?

Comment: My current domain is using my URL root

Answer (score -1):

Every thinks is Ok now. don't use subdomains to host magento 2 :)